# This dynamic button is opens at specific time. But it won't click and break the loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
while (true) {
                try {
                    pressed = pressed.equals(next) ? previous : next;
                    new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofMillis(300)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pressed)).click();
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='www5']")).click();
                    break;

                } catch (StaleElementReferenceException | ElementClickInterceptedException | TimeoutException |
                         NoSuchElementException | UnhandledAlertException | InterruptedException e) {
                    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                    //System.out.println("Exception occurred!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

After enabling this www5 button at specific time it won't click and break the loop.
When executing the code I can clearly see this button clicks(It changes the color).
Help me to find a solution. Thanks

I added thead.sleep to slow down the process and give time to click.